# $\mathbb{E}_\infty$-refinements of the graded tensor product of $\mathbb{Z}$-graded spectra

Tags: homotopy-theory, monoidal-categories, infinity-categories, higher-algebra

The category
$$\mathsf{Gr}_\mathbb{Z}\mathsf{Mod}_R\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\mathsf{Fun}^\otimes(\mathbb{Z}_\mathsf{disc},\mathsf{Mod}_R)$$
of **$\mathbb{Z}$-graded $R$-modules** has a natural monoidal category structure obtained via Day convolution, whose monoidal product is given by

$$(A\otimes_RB)_n\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\bigoplus_{p+q=n}A_p\otimes_RB_q.$$

A natural question then arises: what kinds of braided or symmetric monoidal structures can we put on $\mathsf{Gr}_\mathbb{Z}\mathsf{Mod}_R$ lifting the above monoidal structure?

The answer to this problem goes back to [Joyal–Street](http://maths.mq.edu.au/%7Estreet/JS1.pdf#page=13) and [Eilenberg–Kelly](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-99902-4_22), and can be rephrased as follows:

> First, define the **$2$-category
> $\mathcal{M}_{\mathbb{E}_{2},\mathbb{E}_{1}}(\mathcal{C})$ of braided monoidal refinements of a monoidal category $(\mathcal{C},\otimes_\mathcal{C},\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{C}})$** to be the following (strict) fibre product in the $2$-category of categories:
>
> [image]
>
> Similarly, define the **$2$-category $\mathcal{M}_{\mathbb{E}_{\infty},\mathbb{E}_{1}}(\mathcal{C})$ of symmetric monoidal refinements of $(\mathcal{C},\otimes_\mathcal{C},\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{C}})$** as follows:
>
> [image]
>
> Then, Joyal–Street and Eilenberg–Kelly's result can be stated as the following pair of isomorphisms of *discrete* $2$-categories:
> \begin{align*}
> \mathcal{M}_{\mathbb{E}_{2},\mathbb{E}_{1}}(\mathsf{Gr}_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathsf{Mod}_R) &\cong R^\times,\\
> \mathcal{M}_{\mathbb{E}_{\infty},\mathbb{E}_{1}}(\mathsf{Gr}_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathsf{Mod}_R) &\cong \mathrm{Inv}(R).
> \end{align*}
> (Here $\mathrm{Inv}(R)=\{a\in R\ |\ a^2=1\}$.)

For example, when $R=\mathbb{Z}$, we have $\mathsf{Gr}_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathsf{Mod}_\mathbb{Z}=\mathsf{Gr}_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathsf{Ab}$, which admits only two symmetries:

- The one corresponding to $u=1$, given by $\beta(x\otimes y)=y\otimes x$;
- The one corresponding to $u=-1$, given by the Koszul rule $\beta(x\otimes y)=(-1)^{|x||y|}y\otimes x$.

Meanwhile, for $R=\mathbb{Z}/24$, we have *five* symmetries, corresponding to $u=1$, $5$, $7$, $11$, or $13$.

---

Now, passing to $\infty$-categories, let $\mathcal{C}$ be an $\mathbb{E}_{k}$-monoidal category.

For $k\geq1$, define the **$(\infty,2)$-category of $\mathbb{E}_{k}$-refinements of an $\mathbb{E}_{1}$-monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$** to be the following pullback of simplicial sets:

[image]

Finally, define $\mathsf{Gr}_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathsf{Mod}_R$ for $R$ a ring spectrum by

$$\mathsf{Gr}_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathsf{Mod}_R\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\mathsf{Fun}^\otimes(\mathbb{Z}_{\mathsf{disc}},\mathsf{Sp}),$$
and equip it with the Day convolution $\mathbb{E}_{1}$-monoidal structure.

**Question.** What do we know about the $(\infty,2)$-categories $\mathcal{M}_{\mathbb{E}_k,\mathbb{E}_{1}}(\mathsf{Gr}_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathsf{Mod}_R)$ parametrising $\mathbb{E}_k$-refinements of the Day convolution $\mathbb{E}_1$-monoidal structure on $\mathsf{Gr}_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathsf{Mod}_R$, for $2\leq k\leq\infty$?

Can we describe them in terms of properties of $R$, as in the classical case of $\mathbb{Z}$-graded $R$-modules?